# tower height problem

Tags: calculus, geometry

Let's say we are measuring the height of a tower at two points in the same line from the tower. Point $A$ is at $50\pm1^\circ$ angle towards the tower and point $B$ at $35\pm1^\circ$. The distance between the points is $100\pm1m$. What's the calculated height of the tower and what is how much can the error of measurements be from a differential point of view.

Let's mark $x$ as the distance from tower to point A. distance from tower to B is then $x+100\pm1m$

height of tower is $$h=\sin(35\pm1^\circ)\cdot(x+100\pm1m)$$
$$h=\sin(50\pm1^\circ)\cdot x$$
so $$x=\frac{-\sin(35\pm1^\circ)\cdot100\pm1m}{\sin(35\pm1^\circ)-\sin(50\pm1^\circ)}$$
height $h$ is $$h=\sin(50\pm1^\circ)\cdot \frac{-\sin(35\pm1^\circ)\cdot100\pm1m}{\sin(35\pm1^\circ)-\sin(50\pm1^\circ)}$$

how do I calculate the margin of error? do I have 3 variables in my function for height of the tower? $f(l,\alpha,\beta)$ the 2 angles and the distance?

height $h$ is $$h=\sin(\alpha)\cdot \frac{-\sin(\beta)\cdot l}{\sin(\beta)-\sin(\alpha)}$$
then differential is

$$dh=\frac{\partial h}{\partial \alpha}d\alpha+\frac{\partial h}{\partial \beta}d\beta + \frac{\partial h}{\partial l}dl$$ Does this make any sense?
$$dh=\frac{-\cos(\alpha)\sin^2(\beta)l}{[\sin(\beta)-\sin(\alpha)]^2}d\alpha+\frac{-\cos(\beta)\sin^2(\alpha)l}{[\sin(\beta)-\sin(\alpha)]^2}d\alpha +\frac{-\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)l}{\sin(\beta)-\sin(\alpha)}dl $$

Comment: I assume you mean the angles to point towards the top of the tower. This question does not involve differential equations at all but it does not trigonometry.

Comment: @JohnHabert Propagating the error involves a differential equation (or at least taking a few derivatives).

Comment: @ELEC What are your thoughts on the question? Can you find the height of the tower?

Comment: @IBWiglin True enough. I would just refer to using the total differential as a calculus topic as opposed to a diff. eq. topic.

Comment: I changed $1^o$ to $1^\circ$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Does $\pm1^\circ$ mean you have normally distributed error with standard deviation 1?  Or do you have uniformly distributed error over the interval $[-1,1]$?

Comment: Good question.. I don't know. That wasn't specified.. What do you think? which one is more common?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what the total differential is?

If $f = f(x_1 , x_2 , \cdots , x_n )$ then $$\delta f = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \delta x_i$$

where $\delta f$ is the error in $f$ and $\delta x_i$ is the error in $x_i, i \in \{1,2, \cdots , n\}$.